# Breakpoint Problem in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have an ASP.NET web site project that I want to debug, but when I try to debug it Visual Studio gives the message `"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"`. Does anyone know of a solution to this that does not involve reinstalling everything.
Debug is enabled on those files.

Edit: manually loading symbols did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my specific problem: The startup project was different from the project with the breakpoints, and when I set the startup project to that project the breakpoints worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the assembly that contains the code you are trying to debug is compiled in Debug mode and that PDB symbols are included. Then rebuild the solution and try running again.

Comment: It is compiled in Debug mode, but how do I include the PDB symbols?

Answer (score 1):

You need make sure that you the .PDB files (symbols files) that was generate during the compile time. you can [load the symbols manually](http://beautifulpixels.blogspot.com/2008/12/coder-tip-loading-symbols-in-visual.html) if needed.

Comment: I tried this with every module, then stopped and started debugging again, and the message still appears.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to check if PDB loaded:

1. Pause execution in debugger using pause button;
2. Open Debug windows Modules;
3. select module you are interested in and check location from where it is loaded. If you have PDB file for this module you can load it;

Most common issue with ASP.NET modules are loaded not from your bin but from cache or some other folder.